# is python possible to create a new data frame from the existing data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

i would like to ask about this because i have created a code like this but it returned only the header.

Here is the sample of my df name df_all

```
Doc       name count year
[A1,A2]   John   1   2018
[A1,A3]   Mark   0   2018
[A2,A4]   John   3   2018
```

here is the code that i have tried

```
n_wsp_71 = [i for i in df_all if i.count != 0]
n_wsp_71
```

and here is my results

```
['Doc', 'name', 'count', 'year']
```

but i expect to see this results

```
newdf
        Doc       name count year
        [A1,A2]   John   1   2018
        [A2,A4]   John   3   2018
```

Comment: *That's a dataframe not a list...*

Comment: Try `list_all = list_all[list_all['count'] != 0]`

Comment: im blur, sorry. i have updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You're doing a list comprehension to pandas data-frames, that will never work*

So you have to do:

```
list_all=list_all[list_all['count']!=0]
```

And now:

```
print(list_all)
```

Is:

```
Doc       name count year
[A1,A2]   John   1   2018
[A2,A4]   John   3   2018
```

Comment: @HookIm Happy to help, :-), , *Note: mine is faster based on the timings* `Chirag's: 0.04203809888741396
Mine: 0.010112490249476552`

Comment: ah.. i see! thank you for reminding me to consider the runtime too. by the way, i i would like to return count == 0. when i tried, it has nothing come out. why it became like that?

Comment: @HookIm YW, happy to help again, but why it did not work for `count==0`?, did you try: `df[df['count']==0]`

Comment: yes, already did that. but, i will fix this by myself :) thank you so much!

Comment: @HookIm Hope you do it!!, :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Doc": [["A1","A2"], ["A1","A3"], ["A2","A4"]], "name": ["John", "Mark", "John"], "count": [1,0,3], "year": [2018, 2018, 2018]})

df2 = df.query("count!=0").reset_index(drop=True)

# for count = 0
df2 = df.query("count==0").reset_index(drop=True)

#method 2
df2 = df[~(df["count"].isin(['0']))].reset_index(drop=True)

# for count = 0
df2 = df[(df["count"].isin(['0']))].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
        Doc  name  count  year
0  [A1, A2]  John      1  2018
1  [A2, A4]  John      3  2018

        Doc  name  count  year
0  [A1, A3]  Mark      0  2018
```

Comment: i have not considered using the query before, new thing to learn! thank you. by the way, when i try to show the count that equal to 0. why it shows nothing. is it a sensitive case?

Comment: @HookIm Updated the alternative method. Also for `count=0`